# having a cookie in js save serialized svgs

Tags: javascript, serialization, cookies, svg

so i used this site for reference http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

basically i used their code as a basis to create cookies in js. so basically i have svg tags with elements in the tag that make up the svg. lets say the svg has id=1 so far i've successfully created a cookie that stores the information of the svg. so i have this if statement. if there is a cookie (meaning i've saved the svg into a cookie before) i would unserialize the svg in there and do a document.getElementById(2) = unescape('cookiesvg'). with 2 being the id of another svg tag. the svg tag with 2 on it would be the else case of the if statment. my problem is when i load the information into this tag, it doesnt work.

Comment: You really shouldn't use cookies like this. Also, please post some code so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Note that you are very likely to run into the 4KB limit of cookies if you try to save an SVG of significant complexity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to set an element in the DOM with this:

```
document.getElementById(2) = unescape('cookiesvg')
```

... but that doesn't work; it is called **get** ElementById, not setElementById, right? :)

What you should do instead is set the content of the element instead of trying to set the element itself.  In other words, you'd want to use something like:

```
document.getElementById(2).innerHTML = unescape('cookiesvg')
```

However, I've never used an SVG element, so you might need to do some other SVG-specific thing.  Either way though, what you want to do is set the contents, not the element, and everything should work.